# .htaccess edit for allowing a URL

Tags: html, .htaccess, web

Via the IP deny manager within CPanel, the correct lines of code were added to the .htaccess file in the root dir.

But I don't like the default 403 error. I would rather have it display an image so I can customize the look and message for this error served to the denied visitors.

I added the ErrorDocument line with a link to the html file I am using. This is how it is setup for my wordpress site.

order allow,deny
allow from all

ErrorDocument 403 http://www.mydomain.com/403.htm

[IP here]
[IP here]
Etc...

With this line added, it does attempt to serve the page, but it looks like there is a redirect loop since all files are denied, it can't serve this page. Since I want to use an image within that .htm page I think that would also be blocked unless it was served from another URL outside of my website.

Is there any way to add some code to allow these blocked IP's to only have access to the two URL paths? One for the 403.htm page at root, and another for the .jpg i use in that page which will also be stored at root?

I think this would solve my issue and allow me to serve up this page and graphic to the denied IP's.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

With your `ErrorDocument` directive in `/.htaccess` as

```
ErrorDocument 403 /403.htm
```

Try allowing access using

```
<FilesMatch "403\.(htm|jpg)$">
  order allow, deny
  allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

with both your html and the image file named as `403` (or anything else you may like).

Comment: I did try that one. In fact, I found the default 403.shtml file and edited it to see the contents. The one in root is blank and does not match the message I get when testing a deny on myself. I added some gibberish, saved it and tested but the 403 page didn't change. It looks like it is either pulling the current 403 page from another directory or else there is some kind of theme override.

Comment: What does seem to work is changing the line I am adding to ErrorDocument 403 /403.htm  when I use this one it loads the page, but the address bar shows mydomain.com/  and then the image still does not load from the folder it resides in. I'm closer, i just need to figure out how to allow a file path to an image so that I can link it within the 403.htm file i am serving.

Comment: ok I believe I did this correctly. I placed the top line in the root .htaccess file and added the FilesMatch values to a copy of .htaccess and put that, the 403.htm and the graphic it uses in the no-auth folder. Still no luck.. message states: "You don't have permission to access / on this server. Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: @JonathanSmith Since, /403.htm was working try the new update.

Comment: ok now that I insert that code, the test deny page is simply blank. Absolutely blank, no pagecode at all when inspected. And the header at the top is just mydomain.com with nothing else. I put both the htm and jpg files in the root with htaccess and named them both "403".

Comment: Can you post you complete .htaccess here? Also, check if your cPanel has added access rules in httpd.conf file as well. I can take a look tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
    # BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

    </IfModule>

    # END WordPress

    ErrorDocument 403 /403.htm
    <FilesMatch "403\.(htm|jpg)$">
    order allow,deny
    allow from all
    </FilesMatch>

    deny from [several IP's here]
```